# Where can I find free PHP forms?

Tags: php

There is a question concerning PHP.
Whether there is a product similar on a functional liks [PHP forms](http://phpforms.net/tutorial/html-basics/php-forms.html) but is more cheaper?
Thanks!

Comment: Can't get any cheaper than writing the forms yourself.

Comment: I do not have a similar product, but can offer my writing: http://www.needtodevelop.com/managing-a-web-form-in-php

Answer (score 1):

You can't get free fish, but you can certainly learn how to fish.  Here you go.

```
<form name='formName' action='location of php script' method='post or get'>
    <input name='nameOfInputVar'>
</form>



<?php
    #get vars from URL
    $nameOfInputVar = $_GET['nameOfInputVar'];

    #get vars from post
    $nameOfInputVar = $_POST['nameOfInputVar'];

    //do stuff with vars
?>
```